# Display Network analysis route service in India

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, routing, india

I am working on ArcGIS JavaScript API, I need to display route from one point to another.
Thats why I need any Network Route Service for India. Is there any?

Comment: There in no such service exists in India..please be specific..

Answer (score 3):

Apart from what has been mentioned already, you might consider using [Bing Routing service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/LIBRARY/CC966826.ASPX) that should be available in ArcGIS API for Javascript. I have personally seen the sample working with [ArcGIS API for Silverlight](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/silverlight-api/concepts/index.html#//01660000001s000000) though. The Bing Maps seems to [cover India](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd435699.aspx) geographically, so the routing service should be available there even when accessing programmatically.

Some other alternatives are consuming the routing services from [Nokia](http://developer.here.net/) or [TomTom](http://developer.tomtom.com/) (TomTom might not cover India though) with their APIs and then parsing and visualizing the response in JS API since it comes back what I've seen so far in JSON with the geometry and such.

If you will plan to build your own network analysis services, consider using OSM Planet, for example, available for download for free from http://market.weogeo.com. This will give you access to the roads in India you might use then in ArcGIS for building own network datasets.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, please take a closer look at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-online-network-analysis-rest-api/#/Overview_of_Network_Analysis_Services/02s500000007000000/ and http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgisonline/index.html#//010q000000pt000000.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, no such routing service exists from Esri for India.

**Option 1 - Build your own:**

- Obtain the datasets you need for creating a [Network Analysis Layer.](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/using_Create_Network_Locations/00470000003p000000/)  Might be worth asking a separate Question on obtaining data for India, I am not familiar with what datasets are freely available.
- [Publish this layer within a dynamic map service and enable the network capability.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000002pn000000)
- Consume the service within your JS application and make use of the [RouteTask](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/#sample/routetask_find_route) to enable routing within your application.

**Option 2 - Use Google**

The above might be hard work depending on the data availability.  Perhaps an alternative option would be to use the Google Maps API (read terms of use).

- Overlay your services from ArcGIS Server using [this library.](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn-history/r172/trunk/arcgislink/docs/reference.html)
- Use the [directions service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) to make use of routing within your application.